# In Spring Boot, can I apply an interceptor to one controller without just listing the url path patterns?

Tags: spring-boot, interceptor, request-mapping

I have an `HandlerInterceptor` that I want to only apply to requests that map to a particular `Controller`. I can add the interceptor in a `WebMvcConfigurer` as follows:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final MyInterceptor interceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor).addPathPatterns("/path", "/path/**");
    }
}
```

But this requires me to keep the configuration class in line with the `Controller` by hand. I would like to be able to do this by just saying 'only apply this interceptor to this controller'.
Is this possible in Spring Boot 2.7.

Note: *iff* the `Controller` class has a class-level `@RequestMapping` annotation, this is a slightly more programmatic way of obtaining the path patterns, but not quite the 'all paths to the controller' solution I'd really like.

```
    InterceptorRegistration interceptorRegistration = registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    RequestMapping annotation = controllerClass.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
    for (String rootPath : annotation.value()) {
        interceptorRegistration.addPathPatterns(rootPath, rootPath + "/**");
    }
```

Comment: Currently there isn't. But `/path/**` also matches `/path` if I'm not mistaken so if you pick a common base path for that controller you should be ok. Another option is to check it in the controller itself as it will pass in the actual method being invoked on the controller and you can then check which handler is being invoked.

Comment: @M.Deinum I had code that did the interception logic in every handler method in the controller - there were at least a dozen - and I'm trying to get away from that in the first place to reduce the risk of it being forgotten should someone add another handler method.
However, I will try the /path/** change to see if it covers /path.

Comment: Where do I mention you need to add it to every handler method? I stated that you should add the check to the interceptor.

Comment: My bad, @M.Deinum, I misunderstood. And I hadn't spotted that the interceptor has access to the handling Controller - that's one of the problems with parameters of type Object.

Comment: It is quite clearly stated in the javadoc of the methods.